# Fractions and percentages in MASM - Floating point?

Tags: assembly, masm

I'm extremely new to assembly and I don't think my class has covered floating-point at all. Been searching for solutions for the past few days to display my answer correctly but it won't work.

Here's the snippet of my code:

```
marks1      DWORD   ?     ; int marks = ?                       (EAX) - stored in
mtMarks     DWORD   ?     ; int mtMarks (MID TERM MARKS) = ?    (EBX)
mtPercent   DWORD   ?     ; int mtPercent = ?                   (ECX)
mtResult    DWORD   ?,?
```

and here's the calculation part

```
EQUATION PROC 
    
    mov     eax, marks1
    mov     ebx, mtMarks
    mov     edx, 0
    cdq
    div     ebx
    mov     mtPercent, eax
    mul     ebx
    mov     mtResult, eax
    
    ret         
EQUATION ENDP
```

The output looks like this as I did not use FPU, but we've never learnt it before, is there any way to solve this without using it?

---

Enter marks obtained : 20

Enter the total marks of the Mid Term Test : 30

Enter percentage contribution of Mid Term Test : 50

Mid Term Results (%): +0

---

Comment: You can multiply by 100 *first*, so you get a result like 56 instead of 0.56.  That's called "fixed point".  Often you'd use binary fixed-point (with a scale factor like 256), but decimal fixed-point is useful when you ultimately want a percentage.

Comment: Alright, I've multiplied it and it works now! Thank you

Comment: Please don't edit an answer into the question.  Instead, answer your own question by posting it as an answer.  (You can even accept that answer)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved it:
`((marks1*100/mtMarks)*mtPercent)/100`

```
EQUATION PROC 

    imul    eax, [marks1], 100

    mov     ebx, mtMarks 
    xor     edx, edx

    div     ebx 

    imul    eax, [mtPercent]

    mov     ebx, 100
    xor     edx, edx
    div     ebx 

    mov     mtResult, eax 

    ret
EQUATION ENDP
```

Comment: You can simplify the first 3 instructions to `imul eax, [marks1], 100` there, and `imul eax, [mtPercent]`; you only need to put `100` in another register for `div`.

Comment: Or if you keep the widening `mul` that writes its result to EDX:EAX, then you don't need `cdq`.  In fact, you shouldn't use CDQ with DIV, only with IDIV.  Use `xor edx,edx` to zero EDX before unsigned DIV, if you don't already have a 64-bit number in EDX:EAX.